# Can't connect or even login to phpMyAdmin on Xamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed my port from 3306 to 3310 due to it not being able to start mySQL in the xampp control panel.

That was the only change I made my from the default windows 10 download.

When I go to https://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get these errors and cant log see the log in form.

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Retry to connect

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the right port in your config.inc.php configured.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL 8.0 compatibility problem.

Comment: There is no  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] in that file...